# How to cache the downloaded bitmap using picasso library in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

Hello I am using the `picasso` for downloading the bitmap in android.

Below is my code for this

```
// make sure to set Target as strong reference
private Target loadtarget;

public void loadBitmap(String url) {

    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            // do something with the Bitmap
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed() {

        }
    }

    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
}
```

I want to cache the bitmap so that later on it will pcik from cache instead of download it again. Does this code cache the downloaded bitmap ? If not how to enable
cache using picasso library for downloading the bitmap ?

Comment: Refer: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @VibhorChopra I see it automatically do cache stuff. right ?

Comment: yes,it will cache the image.

Comment: @VibhorChopra Can you please write in answer so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: http://square.github.io/picasso/

It will automatically cache the image.